# Запустить скачанный с GitLab wordpress-сайт на Linux

Tags: linux, wordpress, git

Вопрос глупый, т. к. с этим ранее не работала. Надо доработать wordpress-сайт. Весь он лежит в репозитории на GitLab. Как можно его запустить локально на своем Linux?

Comment: Не работали с GitLab или с Git в принципе? Вот [инструкция](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/start-using-git.html) как развернуть проект.

Comment: git clone и вперёд.

Comment: Можно уточнить несколько вещей? 1) Как я помню, wordpress - сайт хранит контент в базе данных. Она тоже в каком то виде лежит на GitLab? Или сайт может быть "пустым" в тот момент, когда Вы его будете запускать у себя? 2) В чем именно проблема? я вижу такие возможыне причины "как перенести из git на линукс", "как запустить wordpress" - ну, или что то еще...

Answer (score 2):

вопрос очень глобальный, потому привожу только краткий путеводитель по общим шагам. каждый из этих шагов многократно и подробно освещён в интернете, а здесь на сайте есть множество вопросов, связанных с теми или иными трудностями, которые могут встретиться на пути.

---

для работы («свежих» версий) *wordpress* вам [понадобятся](https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/) следующие программы:

1. *php* (версии >= 7.4)
2. *mariadb* (версии >= 10.1) **или** *mysql* (версии >= 5.6)
3. *apache* **или** *nginx*

всё необходимое обязательно наличествует в репозиториях всех популярных дистрибутивов *gnu/linux* и устанавливается с помощью пакетного менеджера.

понятно, что если версия вашего дистрибутива выпущена несколько лет назад, то в ней вполне может не быть требуемых **версий** *php* и *mariadb/mysql*. как тут быть — это отдельная длинная история (тоже многократно освещённая в том числе и на этом сайте).

пожалуй, лучший подход в описанной вами ситуации — установив необходимое, сначала [распаковать и настроить](https://wordpress.org/support/article/how-to-install-wordpress/) «чистую» версию wordpress. а уже убедившись, что *всё работает*, заменить её той, что «лежит в репозитории на gitlab».

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой метод - ставите по этому [мануалу](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ubuntu-18-04-ru) веб сервер с базой данных. В процессе вам будет предложено создать директорию для своего сайта `/var/www/example.com/html`. Вместо создания пустой директории положите свой сайт туда. В корне директории вашего сайта есть файл wp-config. В нем прописываете логин и пароль для базы данных, если на стадии установки WP какие то проблемы с правами или т.п. Как залить дамп базы данных, вы спокойно найдете в интернете. Если у вас что то не получается, обязательно пишите комментарий